# How to make icons larger than "Extra Large" in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want my files view larger than the: "Extra Large" option.

This is what I have now:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

If this is not possible, is there a third party program for file management that does this? I tried Directory Opus but it's limit is 256 px.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible - and asking for Software Recommendations is off topic here.

Comment: It seems that you already have a screenshot of icons larger than _Extra large_?

Comment: @gronostaj The second screen shot is obviously just a photoshoped version of the first screen shot. Just look at it closely and you will see the "pixel stairs" because of the magnification edit.

Comment: @gronostaj I edited the photo above, my dude

Comment: Try holding CTRL and then scroll up or down. I'm sure this will allow you to go to bigger icons. Not sure if the upper limit is what you want

Comment: @LPChip this does not make it larger than Extra Large.

Comment: In my windows 10 the icons are definitely larger than in your example. Then again, your screenshot shows Windows 8, not Windows 10.

Comment: start menu > type "make everything bigger" > change the size of apps and text on the main display > choose something bigger than 100%. Does this work?

Answer (score 2):

Irfanview graphic viewer
https://www.irfanview.com/

Free, no ads, small executable, speedy, simple, feature-rich, supports a huge list of image formats (including HEI and a wide range of RAW formats), with 32 and 64-bit executable for all versions of Windows. It also comes in a portable version.  Only pity is that no Linux/Android version is available.

Fire it up, select "thumbnails" on the main menu - that generates a new window in which to display your thumbnails.  On the new window's main make sure "View->Thumbnails" is ticked.  Then select "options-> set thumbnail options" to set your thumbnail size from a large list of options, and finally select your image folder.  It's easier to do than to describe!

I've used this for many years as a quick and easy image viewer/editor and have no other association than that with those who wrote this wonderful little program.  Small is beautiful.

Comment: Clunky in the extreme but it does work. You can go to thumbnail options and choose any size. Navigating to the directory via tree is awful though.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer will not display icons larger than "Extra Large".
You will need to use another file manager for that.

Some are reviewed in the article
[Best Free File Manager](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-manager.htm),
which does not list my favorite dual-pane
[Altap Salamander](https://www.altap.cz/).

Using Salamander, I found that I could enlarge thumbnails as much as I wanted,
using the shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> (or Scroll up).

I noticed one particularity: For image files that contain thumbnails,
the thumbnail is displayed, meaning that the largest embedded thumbnail
is the most one can get.

However, for image files that did not contain a thumbnail, so that the
file manager needed to create it, the thumbnail could be as large as desired.

Another file manager might do it differently. If it's worth your time,
you could try the ones listed in the above article
(and also in its comments).